# "Login timeout expired" error when setting the sql_alchemy_conn in Airflow for the metadata backend

Tags: sql-server, airflow

> sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@[IP of SQL SERVER]:1433/[DB NAME]?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I know the user name and password is correct and I can use pyodbc in other python project projects so it should not be a firewall problem.  Driver is correctly installed.

Password does not have any characters that would need to be escaped.

Comment: How are actually passing `sql_alchemy_conn` into SQLAlchemy? In some contexts you need to use `...;UID=user;PWD=password` instead of `mssql+pyodbc://user:password@...`

Comment: This is specifically the sql_alchemy_conn  variable in Apache Airflow.